# Print line numbers of duplicate entries

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file in the following format:

```
ABRA CADABRA
ABRA CADABRA
boys
girls
meds toys
```

I'd like to have the line number returned of any duplicate lines, so the results would look like the following:

```
1
2
```

I'd prefer a short one-line command with linux tools. I've tried experimenting with awk and sed but have not had success as of yet.

Comment: Is the input file sorted? If not, would identical non-contiguous lines be counted as duplicates as well?

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
nl file.txt | uniq -f 1 -D | cut -f 1
```

- [`nl`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#nl-invocation) prepends a line number to each line
- [`uniq`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#uniq-invocation) finds duplicates

  - `-f 1` ignores the first field, i.e., the line number
  - `-D` prints (only) the lines that are duplicate
- [`cut`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#cut-invocation)`-f 1` shows only the first field (the line number)

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of sort, uniq, and awk you can use this series of commands.

```
sort File_Name | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I don't want the list of names sorted.

Comment: Then use: cat File_Name |  uniq -c | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: @BryanPoole: better update your answer than answering in a comment - and you don't need `cat` here. Also, did you test this? I don't think it does what you want it to. For starters, the output of `uniq -c` goes into the first field.

Comment: @Benjamin W. Actually went back and re-read what he wanted and it doesn't accomplish what he wants. He wants the line number of every word that has a duplicate. My code would actually just sort the list the return the unique lines.

Comment: @user3299633 Nice improvement on it

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
uniq -d < $file | while read line; do grep -hn "$line" $file; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
perl -e 'my $l = 0; while (<STDIN>) { chomp; $l++; if (exists $f{$_}) { if ($f{$_}->[0]++ == 1) { print "$f{$_}->[1]\n"; print "$l\n"; } } else { $f{$_} = [1,$l]; } }' < FILE
```

Ugly, but works for unsorted files.

```
$ cat in.txt 
ABRA CADABRA
ABRA CADABRA
boys
girls
meds toys
girls
$ perl -e 'my $l = 0; while (<STDIN>) { chomp; $l++; if (exists $f{$_}) { if ($f{$_}->[0]++ == 1) { print "$f{$_}->[1]\n"; print "$l\n"; } } else { $f{$_} = [1,$l]; } }' < in.txt 
1
2
4
6
$
```

**EDIT:** Actually it will shorten slightly:

```
perl -ne '$l++; if (exists $f{$_}) { if ($f{$_}->[0]++ == 1) { print "$f{$_}->[1]\n"; print "$l\n"; } } else { $f{$_} = [1,$l]; }' < in.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

to get all "different" duplicates in all lines you can try:

```
nl input.txt | sort -k 2 | uniq -D -f 1 | sort -n
```

this will not give you just the line numbers but also the duplicate found in those lines. Omit the last sort to get the duplicates grouped together.

also try running:

```
nl input.txt | sort -k 2 | uniq --all-repeated=separate -f 1
```

This will group the various duplicates by adding an empty line between groups of duplicates.

pipe results through

```
| cut -f 1 | sed 's/ \+//g'
```

to only get line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{a[$0]=($0 in a ? a[$0] ORS : "") NR} END{for (i in a) if (a[i]~ORS) print a[i]}' file
1
2
```